# Inviting People To A Party With Limitations

Tags: combinatorics

> A person has 8 friends, of whom 5 will be invited to a party.
>   (b) How many choices if 2 of the friends will only attend together?

Using inclusion-exclusion there are ${8\choose 5}-{2\choose 1}\cdot{6\choose 4}=26$.

Do counting the options that both of them were chosen ${6\choose 3}$  or both where not chosen ${6\choose 5}$, so overall the options are ${6\choose 3}+{6\choose 5}$ is it ok?

Comment: Your arguments are correct!

Comment: Yeah, they are correct. :)